# How do I place something inside of a container in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to place various objects in side of a container (a rectangle in my case). Most of the objects will be in the corners of the rectangle. Is this possible?

```
local rectangle = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
```

Comment: By place in a container do you mean display inside the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you might want to follow the tutorial on scenes [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/04/index.html).

To answer your specific question, you can create "display groups" and add items to it. These function as containers. You can even nest them! Technically these are just lua tables, but Corona uses these as display containers.

As an example:

```
local container = display.newGroup()
local rectangle1 = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
rectangle1:setFillColor(0) --black

local rectangle2 = display.newRect(102,102,96,96)
rectangle2:setFillColor(0.5) --grey

--The order of inserting determines which item will be displayed on top
--Here the black rectangle is on the bottom and the grey one on top of it
container:insert(rectangle1)
container:insert(rectangle2)
```

I still really recommend following the complete tutorial as it will teach you all the basics of programming using the CoronaSDK. All advanced stuff is then locatable using your friend Google (which will either link here or to the Corona Docs).